# TFS 2015 Cards Style enabled only shows for one person

Tags: tfs-2015

I have the setting to show Red for a blocked task and although many people have a blocked task, only one person is showing red for their blocked tasks.

Comment: Does your issue solved or did you check what I mentioned below? Is there any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following to narrow your issue:

- Make sure the rule are set to Task board not Backlog Kanban board.
- Make sure you are seeing the same team project.
- Check those uses could see blocked tasks created by others.
- Try that just set one Rule criteria(Blocked=Yes) without other criteria using some values like `@me, @Today,@Current***`. Check if others could see those blocked tasks.
  [image]
- In the Task board, make sure the **Person** setting is chosen to **All**.

[image]